# Not receiving DMARC reports from major ESPs (gmail, yahoo, hotmail, etc)

Tags: spam, gmail, dmarc

I have recently set up a DMARC record for my domain. DMARC record looks like this, only domain name has been redacted:

```
v=DMARC1; p=none; fo=1; rua=mailto:dmarc-aggregate@domain.com!10m; ruf=mailto:dmarc-forensic@domain.com!10m; sp=reject
```

I'm receiving DMARC aggregate reports from a few ESPs, mostly smaller European ones, and Comcast. However, I'm not receiving anything from Gmail, Yahoo, MSN, etc, and I'm not sure why. I know for a fact that I'm sending e-mails to those ESPs. All the DMARC syntax checkers and record checkers report that the record is correctly formed and live.

Any insight?

Comment: Can you share the full DNS record ? including the record name and type. If you need to redact the domain name please do, but without the full record it's difficult to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 1):

I'm receiving correctly reports from GMail, Yahoo and Hotmail.

Try adding this to your DMARC dns record

```
rf=afrf; ri=86400
```

`rf` sets the type of reporting.

`ri` says you will be receiving one email each 86400 seconds (1 day)

Comment: This is not needed as those are the default values.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the exclamation mark and a size limit at the end of the rua and ruf addresses. According to [this post](https://wordtothewise.com/2014/09/dmarc-report-size-limits/), some parsers might error out on the `!10m`:“!” isn’t a valid unescaped character in a mailto: URI OR it might try and send mail to the domain “example.com!10m”